# Keras: Re-use trained weights in a new experiment

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am quite new to Keras so apologies in advance for any stupid mistakes. I am currently attempting to try out some good old cross-domain transfer learning between two datasets. I have a model here that is trained and executed on a voice recognition dataset that I have generated (code is at the bottom of this question because it's quite long)

If I were to train a new model, say model_2 on a different dataset, then I'd get a baseline from the initial random distribution of weights.

I wonder, is it possible to train model_1 and model_2, then, and this is the bit I don't know how to do; can I take the two 256 and 128 dense layers from model_1 (with trained weights) and use them as starting points for a model_3 - which is dataset 2 with the initial weight distribution from model_1?

So, in the end, I have the following:

1. **Model_1** which starts from a random distribution and trains on **dataset 1**
2. **Model_2** which starts from a random distribution and trains on **dataset 2**
3. **Model_3** which starts from the distribution trained in Model_1 and trains on **dataset 2**.

My question is, how would I go about doing step 3 in the above? I don't want to freeze the weights, I just want an initial distribution for training from a past experiment

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you! Apologies if I didn't make it quite clear enough what I'm going for

My code to train Model_1 is as follows:

```
import numpy
import pandas
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.utils import np_utils
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

import time
start = time.clock()



# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 1
numpy.random.seed(seed)

# load dataset
dataframe = pandas.read_csv("voice.csv", header=None)
dataset = dataframe.values
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
numVars = len(dataframe.columns) - 1
numClasses  =  dataframe[numVars].nunique()
X = dataset[:,0:numVars].astype(float)
Y = dataset[:,numVars]


print("THERE ARE " + str(numVars) + " ATTRIBUTES")
print("THERE ARE " + str(numClasses) + " UNIQUE CLASSES")




# encode class values as integers
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(Y)
encoded_Y = encoder.transform(Y)

# convert integers to dummy variables (i.e. one hot encoded)
dummy_y = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_Y)


calls = [EarlyStopping(monitor='acc', min_delta=0.0001, patience=100, verbose=2, mode='max', restore_best_weights=True)]

# define baseline model
def baseline_model():
    # create model

    model = Sequential()

    model.add(BatchNormalization())

    model.add(Dense(256, input_dim=numVars, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.add(Dense(128, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.add(Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


estimator = KerasClassifier(build_fn=baseline_model, epochs=2000, batch_size=1000, verbose=1)
kfold = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
results = cross_val_score(estimator, X, dummy_y, cv=kfold, fit_params={'callbacks':calls})
print("Baseline: %.2f%% (%.2f%%)" % (results.mean()*100, results.std()*100))
#your code here    
print (time.clock() - start)
```

PS: Input attributes and outputs will all be the same between the two datasets, all that will change are attribute values. I am curious, can this be done if the two datasets have different numbers of output classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, to fine-tune Model_3 from Model_1, just call `model.load_weights('/path/to/model_1.h5', by_name=True)` after `model.compile(...)`. Of course, you must have saved the trained Model_1 first.

If I understood correct, you have the same number of features and classes among the two datasets, so you do not even need to re-design your model. If you had different set of classes, then you had to give different names to the last layers of Model_1 and Model_3:

```
model.add(Dense(numClasses, activation='softmax', name='some_unique_name'))
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very useful - I didn't expect it to be just one line! Would you be able to possibly explain how the above would work if the inputs were different, and the outputs were the same? Eg. In sentiment analysis [pos, neu, neg] classes being shared between two domains but input differing? Is there a way to load hidden layer weights then?

Comment: If you work in the same domain (let's say NLP or image recognition), features mostly remain the same, otherwise the pre-trained model will not be useful. For instance most of NLP tasks operate on fixed-size words embeddings. Technically, if you use dense layers after input, you have to create a new one with the same size and give it a different name. But conceptually it makes little sense.